# Euclidean Distance

Tags: matlab, matrix, euclidean-distance

I have two points

```
 x1 = (a1,b1,c1,d1,e1);    //5 dimensional point
 x2 = (a2,b2,c2,d2,e2);    //5 dimensional point
```

So is this right way to calculate the euclidean dist?

```
  d = sqrt(sqr(a1-a2)+sqr(b1-b2)+sqr(c1-c2)+sqr(d1-d2)+sqr(e1-e2))
```

Now I was wondering if the `pdist(X)` would give me the same result?

Here `X = (x1,x2)` i.e `X` is a 5x2 matrix.

Also I would like the result in square matrix form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of answers to this.  In general, yes, you have the right math, although not the correct Matlab syntax.

Given some X as you describe:

```
X = [1 3 4 2 1; 8 2 3 5 4]
```

Here is the syntax for the equation you were writing out:

```
d1 = sqrt((X(1,1)-X(2,1))^2+(X(1,2)-X(2,2))^2+(X(1,3)-X(2,3))^2+(X(1,4)-X(2,4))^2+(X(1,5)-X(2,5))^2)
```

Here are a couple of more idiomatic ways to format this equation:

```
d2 = sqrt(sum(  (X(1,:) - X(2,:)).^2  ))
d3 = sqrt(sum(       diff(X,[],1).^2))
```

Here is a more functional way to compute it

```
euclidDistance = @(x,y)  sqrt(sum( (x-y).^2));
d4 = euclidDistance(X(1,:), X(2,:))
```

Note, all of these methods return the same result: `d1=d2=d3=d4 = 8.3066`

Answer (score 3):

yes. it is the right way.

For MATLAB use `pdist2(x1,x2,'euclidean')`

Comment: I found pdist not pdist2 . what is your opinion about that ?

Answer (score 3):

Since the Euclidean distance between two vectors is the two-norm of their difference, you can use:

```
d = norm( x1 - x2, 2 )
```

to calculate it. If the second argument is missing, 2-norm is assumed.

Comment: or just norm(x1-x2), since the 2-norm is the default.

Comment: @Chris yes, default 2-norm is assumed.

Comment: But the 2-norm is quite different from euclidean in case of matrix